# My code from react.js is not showing on the web page

Tags: html, reactjs

My code is extreamly simple. I checked all the resources, rewrote the code in different files, updated my PC, checked css file and it worked just fine can't see the problem here.

react.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="react.css">
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"><script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
       <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="react.js" type="text/babel"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

react.js:

````
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello, World!</h1>, document.querySelector("#root"))
```  tried  document.getElementById("root") as well
````

Comment: what did you use to install react? npm i react?

Answer (score 0):

To use `@babel/standalone` you need to load it aswell, otherwise `type="text/babel"` wont work.

```
<!-- Load Babel -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```